# How to configure the "mail" command to use an SMTP relay server without using sendmail service?

Tags: email, smtp, exchange

Since I new to redhat ver 6 linux I wanted to know how I can configure our web server that is running redhat to used out exchange 2010 relay. I already configure our exchange 2010 to allow  our web server to used it as relay. How can I view the current settings or how can I configure our web server to used the smtp protocol. What are the commands to do this

Answer (score 1):

The "mail" command will try to run /usr/sbin/sendmail locally to deliver the email message. "mail" is a MUA (Mail User Agent), while sendmail is a MTA (Mail Transport Agent).

If you want "mail" to deliver to a fixed relay, you can either install sendmail and configure that to do what you want, or alternatively install "ssmtp" which is specifically designed for this task. It installs itself as /usr/sbin/sendmail so that "mail" can run it as usual. I believe "ssmtp" is not included in Red Hat, but I'm sure that an RPM should be available somewhere. See [here](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/132006) for a description of ssmtp.